# Drawing onto PNG instead of onto window using SFML

Tags: c++, png, sfml

I am creating a platformer game using SFML, and my "Level Size" is a lot larger than my window size. So I am using sf::View to move around the view while I move.

What I do every frame is:

1. I draw everything onto the window
2. Set the view to be part of the
   window
3. Run window.display()
4. Run window.clear()

What I want to do now, however, is to draw each element onto an image (.png) file. A couple of details:

- This image should be the same size as my "Level Size"
- I don't want it zoomed in anyway - it should not be affected by my current window or view
- Finally there are transparent parts of the image, because I have not drawn them onto my canvas. I do not want these black in my image, but rather transparent

How can I achieve this? Ideally I would like to run a function like this: exportPNG(string filename, level).
Thanks a lot!

Comment: see `sf::RenderTexture`.

Comment: @Dundee I actually completely agree with you here. The SFML forum gave me all the advice I needed and it was sort of thing that you could easily post as an answer if you knew what it was. That being said, a comment is better than nothing, and I have sympathy if you don't quite know or don't have the time.

Comment: No because if he posted nothing I, as the questioner would be left clueless. In the end the goal is to help people as much as possible

Comment: To be honest I forgot about the existence of this post until you came along, since the problem was sorted out long ago. Often communication in stack overflow feels kinda pointless because it doesn't lead anywhere, asking @H what he meant would be like that. So is this conversation :)

Comment: Or not because I have things to do, sorry

Comment: @Dundee: you're wrong on at least two things. ;-) I wrote only that comment because I had no time to provide a full answer and I supposed (hopefully correctly) that the OP would read the doc about that class (which is, btw, very easy to find). Better that than nothing. Secondly, I don't think copy/pasting the doc here is really useful. If I had some value to add on top of it, why not. But that's not the case.